# Cannot do Solr searching because of disabling replication

Tags: search, solr, replication

I try to do Solr searching but I cannot. Solr give me the error message:

> Update failed, could not disable replication for 'core name_en' - Request to http://:3000/core/core name_en/replication%2Fupdate failed - 500 Internal Server Error

I try to comment the replication on solrconfig.xml but it's ok for a first few times but the problem is come back again.

I try to disable replication by running this command on the browser: http://:3000/core/core name_en//replication?command=disablereplication

but I got HTTP 404

Where should I fix it? Solr slave server?

Comment: What is the error on the Solr Server? (the 500 error probably has an stack trace or error message attached on the server side)

Comment: @MatsLindh   "HTTP Status 500 - unable to create new native thread"